Is it possible to write short stories without any humor, comedy, or jokes?
Would it be possible to write short stories without any humor, comedy, or jokes?
I am looking into writing short stories, but I am not very skilled as a writer and very much end up getting caught up in background details. So I prefer writing in a screenplay type of manner, or short stories.
With that in mind, I also don't consider myself having much of a sense of humor. Spontaneous, witty jokes is all I can play off at best. Not enough to write any comedic elements, though.
So, is there any way to learn or improve how to write comedic aspects, or can I just write without them?

Welcome to Writing.SE! I believe that the answers to the linked duplicate should help you.

@F1Krazy I don't think the answers to the linked "duplicate" will be helpful for the person asking this quesiton. The other question is about a "very dark" "trilogy". Long fiction works differently than short stories. Where, as the answers to that question suggest, long fiction might require some intermittent relief from a grimdark story, a short story can remain sober or humorless throughout due to its brevity. The end will bring the relief soon enough.

1
I wouldn't attempt to write something that I cannot relate to. You very likely won't be able to write it well. It is better to write about what you know.
2
I am surprised that you ask whether short stories can be written without humorous elements. You must not be very familiar with short stories, because it seems to me that the majority of short stories aren't humorous.
I would recommend that you find some contemporary collections of short stories or magazines that publish them, ideally within your own genre, and read a whole lot of them to get an idea what topics and styles are currently common.
To be clear:
Short stories can be earnest and without humor, and many (if not most) are. Don't worry about that.
